# When I try to complete the process of "How to delete all text except for what's inside quotation marks?" nothing occurs and no edits were made?

Tags: notepad++

How to delete all text except for what's inside quotation marks?" nothing occurs and no edits were made?

This is what I did:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

- Find what: `(?:^|\G)[^“”]*(“[^”]*”)`
- Replace with:  `$1` (Note: there is a space before `$1`)
- Check Wrap around
- Check Regular expression
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Use `SKIP` and `FAIL` verbs:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `".+?"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|.`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **TICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
".+?"           # match something inside quotes
(*SKIP)         # skip it
(*FAIL)         # and consider the match has failed
  |               # OR
.               # any character
```

[Demo & Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/jwkMif/1)

---

Another way:

- Find what: `(".+?")|.`
- Replace with:  `$1`

[Demo & Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/f4tz5U/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Find what : `.+?((?<=")[^ ]+(?="))|"[^"]+$`
- Replace with : `\1\n`
- Regular expression : Checked
- `. matches newline` : Checked

Inspired by this
[Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19721726/regex-in-textpad-remove-all-text-that-is-not-enclosed-inside-quote).

Comment: this has been very frustrating... the formula look right but after entering Replace, it stated replace 1302 Occurrence were replaced in selected text and on line 1303,  its has a 282 long words line.   But the formula didnt extract everything except what is inside of the quotes...

Comment: Isn't extracting everything inside of the quotes is what you asked for? If the above doesn't work for you, plus add to your question a sample of your data.